# Pass info between tag helpers?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am writing a set of tag helpers that target, for example, `<form>` and `<input>` elements. I want to add a custom attribute to the `<form>` element, and retrieve the value of that attribute in the contained `<input>` element. So, if my HTML looks like this:

```
<form xx-value='123'>
  <input asp-for='Something' />
</form>
```

then in my `InputTagHelper` I would want to retrieve the value 123 that was specified for the `xx-value` attribute.

**Is there a designed-in way to pass data like this between tag helpers?**

Consider the case where I have this markup:

```
<form xx-value='123'>
  <input asp-for='Something' />
</form>
<form>
  <input asp-for='SomethingElse' />
</form>
```

In this case, the first invocation of the `InputTagHelper` would get the value 123. But the second invocation of the `InputTagHelper` would get a value of 0 since its parent `<form>` tag didn't specify the magic xxx-value attribute.

Comment: Perhaps a [View component](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#invoking-a-view-component-as-a-tag-helper) is more suitable in this case.

Comment: For Asp.Net Core tag, there is no builtin feature to achieve your requirement, you may consider trying Front framework like vue or angular instead of Razor View. Or, you need to implement your own tag, and you could refer [Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer (which doesn't work for `<form>` and `<input>` tags - see blow) is for the "parent" tag helper to store the value in the `context.Items` dictionary and for the "child" tag helper(s) to retrieve the value from that same dictionary. A Google search for "child tag helper" yields many examples of this scheme.

The problem with this answer (in the context of the OP) is that, for some reason, the `<form>` tag helper executes **after** its child `<input>` tag helper. So, rather than receiving the value from the parent `FormTagHelper`, the `InputTagHelper` discovers that the `context.Items` dictionary is empty.

I created [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56625896/1637105) to ask about that weird behavior.