# Tag helper order of execution

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am writing a set of ASP.Net Core tag helpers that target (among other tags) `<form>` and `<input>` tags. My `<form>` tag helper defines a custom attribute, the value of which it wants to pass to the child elements.

All of the articles I've read make this sound simple: The parent tag helper stores the value in the `context.Items` dictionary, and the children read it from that same dictionary.

This implies that **the child tag helpers execute after the parent tag helper.** However, I've discovered that, in the case of `<form>` and `<input>` tag helpers, the `FormTagHelper` executes **after** the `InputTagHelper`.

By way of example, consider this HTML:

```html
<form my-attr='Hello'>
  <input asp-for='SomeProperty' />
</form>
```

My form tag helper:

```cs
public class FormTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string MyAttr { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<form>");
        context.Items.Add("my-attr", MyAttr ?? "");
    }
}
```

Input tag helper:

```cs
public class InputTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<input>");
        var valueFromParentForm = context.Items["my-attr"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I would expect `valueFromParentForm` to be `"Hello"`, but in fact it throws an exception because the context.Items dictionary is empty.

What is this is all about, and what might I do to work around this weird, inside-out order of execution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

Aside for [`Process()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.taghelper.process?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelper_Process_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperContext_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperOutput_) method the base tag helper provides also [`Init()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.taghelper.init?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelper_Init_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Razor_TagHelpers_TagHelperContext_) method. It's summary:

> Initializes the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.ITagHelper` with the given context. Additions to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperContext.Items` should be done within this method to ensure they're added prior to executing the children.

Simply override this method and add whatever you need:

```cs
public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
{
    context.Items.Add(1, "Init FormTagHelper");
}
```

---

## Explanation

For your html code:

```html
<form my-attr='Hello'>
  <input asp-for='SomeProperty' />
</form>
```

let's have two tag helpers:

#### FormTagHelper

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("form")]
public class FormTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
    {
        context.Items.Add(1, "Init FormTagHelper");
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        context.Items.Add(4, "Process FormTagHelper");
    }
}
```

#### InputTagHelper

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("input")]
public class InputTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
    {
        context.Items.Add(2, "Init InputTagHelper");
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        context.Items.Add(3, "Process InputTagHelper");
    }
}
```

To understand better **in what order** methods are called let's take a look at this diagram:

[image: TagHelpers execution timeline]

I think the execution order is pretty self-explanatory. But what about the red `No access` part? Let's starts with establishing what exactly `Items` dictionary is and how it works. It figures as `IDictionary<object, object>` but it is not a regular dictionary. It's a [`CopyOnWriteDictionary`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Shared/CopyOnWriteDictionary/CopyOnWriteDictionary.cs) and it is quite special. It has two underlying dictionaries `ReadDictionary` and `WriteDictionary` and it calls either of them depending on what type of action (read/write) is currently performed.

While you can add `1` from `FormTagHelper.Init()`, you won't be able to access keys `2` and `3` from `FormTagHelper.Process()` despite the fact that according to the diagram they should already be there:

[image: desc]

That's because values for `InputTagHelper` are being add to `_innerDictionary` not `_sourceDictionary` which is then used in `FormTagHelper`. Such behaviour creates one-way access to `Items` dictionary. Children tag helpers are able to access values added by parents, but not the opposite way.

State of `Items` dictionary after execution of `Init()` method of `InputTagHelper()`:

[image]

Comment: On so many levels, the missing pieces from the ms-docs - thanks @Prolog

Answer (score 0):

I just run now the following tag helpers (parent and children)

```
<sp-row>
  <sp-col>Child 1</sp-col>
  <sp-col>Child 2</sp-col>
</sp-row>
```

and It's run in the following order (And not in the previews answer's order):

1. Parent's Init(TagHelperContext context)
2. Parent's ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
3. Parent's Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
4. Child1's Init(TagHelperContext context)
5. Child1's ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
6. Child1's Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
7. Child2's Init(TagHelperContext context)
8. Child2's ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
9. Child2's Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)

Comment: I I understood why this happened!

Comment: Only if I called await output.GetChildContentAsync(); inside the parent processAsync method then it's await the children Init to be run before process method of the parent